# Minified APK crashes at run-time

Tags: java, android, apk, minify, signed

I generate a signed apk and when i launch it it’s crash just after i sign in.

but when i launch the app without signed apk, normally on the emulator it's work fine.

This is the logcat:

```
2020-06-08 21:53:17.293 6729-6729/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

    --------- beginning of crash
2020-06-08 21:53:17.294 6729-6729/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.diplomate.sasiraj, PID: 6729
    java.lang.InternalError
        at q.m.d.j.z.a(Unknown Source:14)
        at q.m.d.j.i.<clinit>(Unknown Source:4)
        at q.m.d.b.a(Unknown Source:6)
        at q.m.d.b.<init>(Unknown Source:16)
        at q.m.d.b.<init>(Unknown Source:3)
        at q.m.d.e$a.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at q.m.d.e.<clinit>(Unknown Source:73)
        at q.b.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.diplomate.sasiraj.Payment.v.createEphemeralKey(Unknown Source:30)
        at com.stripe.android.EphemeralKeyManager.retrieveEphemeralKey(Unknown Source:37)
        at com.stripe.android.EphemeralKeyManager.<init>(Unknown Source:45)
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession.<init>(Unknown Source:101)
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession.<init>(Unknown Source:44)
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession$Companion.initCustomerSession(Unknown Source:34)
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession$Companion.initCustomerSession$default(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession.initCustomerSession(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.diplomate.sasiraj.Customer.CustomerMapActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field producerIndex in class Lq/m/d/j/i; (declaration of 'q.m.d.j.i' appears in base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
        at q.m.d.j.z.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at q.m.d.j.i.<clinit>(Unknown Source:4) 
        at q.m.d.b.a(Unknown Source:6) 
        at q.m.d.b.<init>(Unknown Source:16) 
        at q.m.d.b.<init>(Unknown Source:3) 
        at q.m.d.e$a.<init>(Unknown Source:0) 
        at q.m.d.e.<clinit>(Unknown Source:73) 
        at q.b.a(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.diplomate.sasiraj.Payment.v.createEphemeralKey(Unknown Source:30) 
        at com.stripe.android.EphemeralKeyManager.retrieveEphemeralKey(Unknown Source:37) 
        at com.stripe.android.EphemeralKeyManager.<init>(Unknown Source:45) 
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession.<init>(Unknown Source:101) 
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession.<init>(Unknown Source:44) 
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession.<init>(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession$Companion.initCustomerSession(Unknown Source:34) 
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession$Companion.initCustomerSession$default(Unknown Source:10) 
        at com.stripe.android.CustomerSession.initCustomerSession(Unknown Source:9) 
        at com.diplomate.sasiraj.Customer.CustomerMapActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:29) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-06-08 21:53:17.300 1852-2998/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.diplomate.sasiraj/.Customer.CustomerMapActivity
2020-06-08 21:53:17.314 6729-6729/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6729 SIG: 9
2020-06-08 21:53:17.326 1852-1867/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
2020-06-08 21:53:17.327 1852-1867/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2020-06-08 21:53:17.328 1609-1609/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/6729/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2020-06-08 21:53:17.427 1852-1927/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'f74e236 com.diplomate.sasiraj/com.diplomate.sasiraj.Login.LauncherActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2020-06-08 21:53:17.427 1852-1927/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f74e236 com.diplomate.sasiraj/com.diplomate.sasiraj.Login.LauncherActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: How are you using the apk? on real device or emulator? And can you also add your gradle file. Is minifyenabled true?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of this or all in the same sequence:

1) make minifyEnabled false in gradle

2) Invalid and restart android studio

3)After start make sure to Sync and rebuild project

and then try. Most probably it is because of progaurd rules. App is obfuscating/bifurcating your classes. But this is temporary solution. You should'nt keep minifyEnabled false and release the app.

4) And most important, write progaurd rules properly as per your use-case and then make/set minifyEnabled true again. Then it wont crash Refer official android doc for that or this link

> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: Setting `minifyEnabled` to false is NEVER the answer.

Comment: @Zun it ```NEVER IS THE ANSWER, EVERYONE KNOWS.```  But if he is not looking for obfuscation of files and progaurd rules are not written properly, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: The goal of the original poster is to achieve minification without issues with Proguard. Suggesting to disable minification is not an answer. There is not a single GOOD developer on earth who has minifyEnabled set on false.

Comment: @Zun I have edited the answer. The former answer was just for temporary use, so that it doesn't crash for him in release variant atleast.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make minifyEnabled false in gradle and the app is not crash but the google maps is not show

i using the apk on the emulator and i try on the device too

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'.  

android {.  

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.diplomate.chauffeur"
        minSdkVersion 21
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : '',
                                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE']
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility '1.8'
        targetCompatibility '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.16'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.13.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:13.1.3'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'

    implementation "com.github.addisonelliott:SegmentedButton:3.1.5"

    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rtchagas:pingplacepicker:1.1.2'

    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'


    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


    /* Needed for RxAndroid */
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'


    /* Needed for Rx Bindings on views */
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'


    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0' //Proguard
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0' //Proguard
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0' //Proguard

    /* Used for server calls */
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'

    /* Used to make Retrofit easier and GSON & Rx-compatible*/
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    /* Used to debug your Retrofit connections */
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.3'

    implementation "com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.3.4"
    implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:3.0.3'

    implementation 'com.shreyaspatil:MaterialDialog:2.1'

    // Material Design Library
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.ncorti:slidetoact:0.7.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: i forgot to put the google map api. and i change the minifyEnabled false in gradle and it's all work thank you